# jQuery.ajaxを用いた通信での戻り値の問題

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

InstascanをもちいてQRコードを読み込み、その値をもちいて処理を行うプログラムを作成しておりJSON形式で値を得たいのですがphpの中身がまるごと返てきてしまっています(以下のエラーが出ます)。

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

以下のajaxはInstascanで読み込んだあとに実行され、idには読み込んだQRコードの値(数字限定)が入るようになっています。

どのような変更を行えば良いかご教授願います。

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "search.php",
 data: { "id": id },
 dataType: "json",
}) .done (function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
 console.log("OK!!");
 console.log(data.name);
}) .fail (function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
 console.log("Error!!");
});
```

search.php

```
<?php
 $id = $_POST["id"];
 $name = 'ブックマーク';
 //SQLでidを処理し、一致するnameを返す予定。
 $arr = array(
  'id' => $id,
  'name' => $name
 );
 header('Content-type:Application/json; charset=utf8');
 echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

--追記--
簡易的なプログラム(一部省略)を書いて試しましたが上のプログラムと同様のエラーが発生しうまく行きません。
ちなみにphp単体で叩くと

```
{"id":null,"name":"ブックマーク"}
```

このように適切にjson形式で返ってきます。

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ja">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="ボタン">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(function() {
    $("[type=button]").on("click", function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "sample.php",
        data: {"id": "020001"},
        dataType: "json"
      }) .done (function(data) {
        console.log("ok");
        console.log(data.name);
      }) .always(function(){
        console.log("hahaha");
      });
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

sample.php

```
<?php
  $id = $_POST["id"];
  $arr = array(
    "id" => id,
    "name" => "ブックマーク"
  );
  header("Content-type:Application/json;charset=utf8");
  echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: 「phpの中身がまるごと返てきてしまっています」とありますが、そう判断した根拠はなんですか？ブラウザのデベロッパーツールで実際のレスポンスが確認できるはずなので確認してみてください。また、わざわざServices_JSONを用いている必要はありますか？PHP5.2以降において `json_encode`が利用できるので外部PEARパッケージは不要かと思うのですが。

Comment: @hinaloe phpの〜については、戻り値がdataに格納されているはずであり、その中身をコンソールに出力したところphpの中身がまる‌​ごと入っていたためです。

Comment: 「phpの中身がまるごと返てきて」いるのを確実に確かめられたのであれば、見直すべきはコードの中身ではなく、Webサーバの設定でしょう。`.php`が確実にphpスクリプトとして実行されているかは確認されていますか？「php単体で叩く」とは何をしたのでしょうか？

Comment: @OOPer サーバ側の設定がうまく行っておらず、phpスクリプトを実行できない状態だったのが問題でした。アドバイスありがとうございます